# Using Timer to achieve typewriter Effect in JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, timer

I am making a text adventure game and have run into an issue where I cannot get some of my text display in the fashion I want it to. When entering some words the player could initiate the introduction of a new room. I would want this introduction to have the "typewriter" effect. This event would need to take place in my programs ActionPerformed method. For example when the user types "Move" and then hits enter, I would want the resulting text to print one character at a time.

Here is the current method I use outside of ActionPerformed to achieve this effect:

```
public void slowPrint(String message, long millisPerChar)
{
    //makes it so that the player cannot input while the text is being displayed
    userinput.setEditable(false);
     String o;
        for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++)
        {
            //adds each letter one-by-one
            o = "" + message.charAt(i);
            output.append(o);

            //moves the JTextArea to the bottom
            output.setCaretPosition (output.getDocument ().getLength ());

            //delay so that you can see each letter being added
            try {
                Thread.sleep(millisPerChar);;
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace(); }
        }
    //after the text is displayed allow the user to input again
    userinput.setEditable(true);
  }
```

How can I get a similar method to work with the use of the Timer class so that it does not prevent my thread from updating the GUI.

This is what my action performed looks like with relevant methods:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
        s = userinput.getText();
        output.append("\n");
        userinput.setText("");

        for (int i = 0; i<whatRoom.length; i++)
        {
            if (whatRoom[i])
            {
                switch(i)
                {
                    case 0:
                        controlOne(s);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

And the "controlOne()" method:

```
private void controlOne(String s)
{   
    if(one.getHasLight() == true)
    {
        if(!one.getPushYes())
        {
            output.append(one.dealWithLight(s, output));
        }

        else output.append(one.commands(s));
    }
    else output.append(one.commands(s));
}
```

Instead of appending all the time I would want to use something similar to my "slowPrint" method.

Hopefully this made some sense and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two essential values of a [`Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) are

1. The delay
2. The `ActionListener`

If you create the timer inside your `slowPrint` method, it is important to keep a reference to it, so you can stop it later. Therefore you must add the `ActionListener` later. Inside the `ActionListener` you could keep track of the current text position by an additional variable (forget about the for-loop). Then you just have to check manually if all text has been printed, and stop the timer accordingly.

If you want the delay to also take place initially, just call `timer.setInitialDelay(delay)`.

[image: GIF]

---

Example with your `slowPrint` method modified:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Foo {

    private JTextField input;
    private JTextArea output;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new Foo().createAndShowGUI());
    }

    public void createAndShowGUI() {
        output = new JTextArea();
        output.setEditable(false);

        input = new JTextField();
        input.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                slowPrint("This is a test answer.\n", 100);
            }
        });

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
        contentPane.add(input, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        contentPane.add(output);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void slowPrint(String message, int millisPerChar) {
        input.setEditable(false);
        input.setFocusable(false);

        Timer timer = new Timer(millisPerChar, null);
        timer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            int counter = 0;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                output.append(String.valueOf(message.charAt(counter++)));
                output.setCaretPosition(output.getDocument().getLength());
                if (counter >= message.length()) {
                    timer.stop();
                    input.setEditable(true);
                    input.setFocusable(true);
                    input.requestFocusInWindow();
                }
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }

}
```