# typewriter effect with JTextArea and Scanner JAVA

Tags: java, timer, jtextarea

I'm making a game with my teammate for a school project.
I have created a JTextArea where the lines of a text file would be printed.
I would like to add the typeWriter effect, therefore I searched for answers on   this website.
I found some pretty information here :
[java-add-typewriter-effect-to-jtextarea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43333999/java-add-typewriter-effect-to-jtextarea)
[using-timer-to-achieve-typewriter-effect-in-jtextarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39283063/using-timer-to-achieve-typewriter-effect-in-jtextarea)
I tried the solutions above, without success.

I'll put my code :

```
    public static void ui() {

    Font baseText = new Font("Roboto", Font.PLAIN, 30);

    JFrame mainWindow = new JFrame("Main Window");

    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.setFont(baseText);
    textArea.setLineWrap(true);
    textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    textArea.setEditable(false);

    JPanel panelButton = new JPanel();
    panelButton.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    JButton bContinue = new JButton("Continue");
    bContinue.setFont(baseText);

    Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("beginning.txt");
    try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(path);
        while(sc.hasNextLine()){
            slowDisplay(line, textArea);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Game.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    mainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    panelButton.add(bContinue);
    mainWindow.add(textArea);
    mainWindow.add(panelButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    mainWindow.setBounds(0, 0, 1920, 1080);
    mainWindow.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Here is the content of the slowDisplay Method :

```
    public static void slowDisplay(String line, JTextArea textArea){
    Timer timer = new Timer(500, null);
    timer.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        int index=0;

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          if(index<line.length()){
              textArea.append(String.valueOf(line.charAt(index++)));
          }
          else if(index==line.length()){
              textArea.append("\n");
          }
          else{
              timer.stop();
          }
        }

    });
    timer.start();

}
```

What it does is that it browses the columns of the text files and write the characters, it creates something awful, unreadable and I don't know why :
[The thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhMn7.png)

I'll put the content of my text file :

- -Mmmh...
- -I-I feel cold. Where am I?
- -Huh? Is this thing where I'm lying is a human sized plant?!
- I looked around, I saw nothing but trees, bushes, and plants.
- -What the...

If someone can guide me please, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I have also tried typewriter effect way long ago.
Instead i used Thread.sleep() function to perform this task.

So here is the method for it.

```
 void typeEffect(String str,JTextArea textArea)throws Exception{

     //loop through each character and append it to the JTextArea
      for(int i==0;i<str.length();i++){

         textArea.append(str.charAt(i)+"");

          Thread.sleep(20);//stops for 20 milliseconds


       }

}
```

This looks very simple.

**EDIT 1:-**

I Have this code which is working as required.

```
 import javax.swing.*;

    class DelayTest
    {

        public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
        {
            JFrame f=new JFrame("Main Frame"); 
            JTextArea textA=new JTextArea();

             f.setSize(720,600);
             f.add(textA);
             f.setVisible(true);
             typeEffect("Hello This is a sample String",textA);
        }

         static void typeEffect(String str,JTextArea textArea)throws Exception{

         //loop through each character and append it to the JTextArea
          for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){

             textArea.append(str.charAt(i)+"");

              Thread.sleep(100);//stops for 100 milliseconds
             }//closing of loop
         }//closing of method
  }//closing of class
```

I have executed this code and found it working.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Unfortunately, it does not work int my case, because I use GUI. Although I tried your method, it processed as if there was no sleep.

Comment: @Tronos i have edited my answer to provide a working code.

Comment: Again, thank you for answering me. I don't know why your solution does not work on my project, I precisely wrote everything, however it seems that Thread.sleep can't work with Graphical User Interface, it somehow stops the refreshing. That is why I chose a timer.  

Anyway, I found that what was wrong was my while loop.  
Indeed, it loaded a new line everytime slowDisplay() was done. So, now I load every lines in a string, and it works as intented.
Thank you still !